# Why is there a "right-wing" tag but no "left-wing" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a [right-wing](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/right-wing) tag but no [left-wing](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-wing) tag.

Why is this? Do we need to do something about this?

Comment: There's [tag:left], which is a synonym for [tag:ideology]. I'm not sure if [tag:right-wing] is worth keeping btw, as it's very broad. Can someone be an expert in "right wing"? Dunno... Maybe it's a good idea to retag those questions with [tag:conservatism] and others with [tag:ideology]?

Answer (score 6):

Tags aren't created in isolation, they don't exist until they are first added to a question. So, the simple answer is that we don't have a [left-wing] tag because no one thought their question would benefit from it.

Do you have example questions where you feel the tag would be appropriate? If so, please share, adding a tag to them is trivial.

Comment: thanks for agreeing right-wing benefitted them all :) no there is no question at all which will benefit , infact it will be inappropriate to have left-wing tag :) now i know what and how it happened to greece govt.

Comment: @Raaj If you feel [right-wing] is inappropriate and should be removed, please create a new Meta discussion about it. If you decide to do so, please try to explain your reasoning in as neutral a way as possible and don't be shy with actual examples of bad use of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stealing the answer from Carpetsmoker's comment - it's because "left-wing" is a bad tag (too broad and too vague). So's "right-wing", for the same reasons, and as such I would personally would be in favor of deleting it.

Comment: Having looked at the questions tagged that way, the conclusion about deleting the tag is even more obvious. Half of them are (intentional or not) attempts to smear anyone on the "right" by tagging questions about extremism with "right-wing", which is incorrect use of the tag even if the tag was a good one.